# Pytorch version for cuda 12.2

Tags: pytorch, gpu, version, nvidia

I am unable to find the Pytorch version for cuda driver 12.2. Can anyone please guide me where can I find any material that helps.

I have installed currently pytorch version 11.7. While training the model i am facing following error.

**
RuntimeError(CUDA_MISMATCH_MESSAGE.format(cuda_str_version, torch.version.cuda)

The detected CUDA version (12.2) mismatches the version that was used to compile
PyTorch (11.7). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.**

PS : I have nvidia driver 535

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same issue. It appears that the PyTorch version for CUDA 12.2 is not out yet.

Here are the few options I am currently exploring. Still haven't decided which one I'll end up using:

1. Using an NGC Container 
   https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/pytorch 
   This is essentially like a virtual environment with the required CUDA drivers and everything included.
2. Downgrading to CUDA 12.1 and installing the nightly version 
   https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu121 
   Not sure exactly the driver version I would need for this but it could be a viable option.
3. Just waiting and hoping they release it soon
4. (Most Likely) I will just build it from the source.
   https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/104417

**References** 
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/which-version-of-cuda-12-1-should-be-used/176456
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-for-cuda-12/169447/2

Answer (score 4):

You can install the nightly build.  Note you should have `cudnn` installed already, I am using cudnn v8.9.3.  The 12.1 PyTorch version works fine with CUDA v12.2.2:

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch-nightly -c nvidia`

Answer (score 2):

With python 3.10, NVIDIA driver version `535.104.05` and CUDA version `12.2` I found that this works:
`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue of `Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled`. Here are the steps I took:

1. Created a new conda environment

   `conda create -n newenv python=3.10`

   `conda activate newenv`
2. Installed pytorch-nightly

   `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch-nightly -c nvidia`
3. Check if the CUDA is compatible with the installed PyTorch by running

   `import torch`

   `print(torch.cuda.is_available())`

It would return True if the CUDA is configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Llama-2, I think you need to downgrade Nvida CUDA from 12.2 to 10.2. Version 10.2 is the most stable version. Pytorch version 1.5 works with Pytorch for CUDA 10.2.  However, the problem I have is it seems Anaconda keeps downloading the CPU libaries in Pytorch rather than the GPU. Not sure why.